# Mail.ReadBasic (delegated) - is there a permission other than FullAccess to make this work on OTHER mailboxes?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-mail

I would like to be able to harness the same power as Mail.ReadBasic.All, but delegated so that I login as myself and audits see me, not some generic app.  Use case:

ThreatHunting.Read.All + Mail.ReadBasic so that I can find messages which failed DMARC and then pull down their InternetMessageHeaders property so that I can review Authentication-Results, DKIM-Signatures, etc.

Mail.ReadBasic not having access to the body or previewBody seems ideal.  Mail.ReadBasic.Shared might be the answer, but the main two things I'm trying to avoid:

1. using application permissions
2. Granting myself FullAccess to mailboxes when all I want is the Subject and the message headers.

I feel like I haven't tried anything because nothing is available, and I'm hoping that somebody will enlighten me with some good news.